# Turn linked Objects into Stream or Collection

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I want to iterate over a stacktrace.
The stacktrace consists of throwables whose getCause() returns the next throwable. The last call to getCause() returns null. (Example: a -> b -> null)

I've tried to use Stream.iterable() which results in a NullPointerException, since the elements in the iterable can't be null.
Here is a short demonstration of the problem:

```
  public void process() {
      Throwable b = new Throwable();
      Throwable a = new Throwable(b);
      Stream.iterate(a, Throwable::getCause).forEach(System.out::println);
  }
```

I'm currently using a while loop to create a collection manually:

```
public void process() {
    Throwable b = new Throwable();
    Throwable a = new Throwable(b);

    List<Throwable> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Throwable element = a;
    while (Objects.nonNull(element)) {
      list.add(element);
      element = element.getCause();
    }
    list.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
  }
```

Is there a better way (shorter, more functional) to achieve this?

Comment: no. You have a nested data structure. streams and collections assume sequential data. You need a transformation to get from one to the other.

Comment: Instead of creating a temporary `List` you could use [Stream.Builder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.Builder.html)

Comment: @f1sh since when is a stack not sequential?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think that you can do a recursive call here:

```
static Stream<Throwable> process(Throwable t) {
    return t == null ? Stream.empty() : Stream.concat(Stream.of(t), process(t.getCause()));
}
```

Comment: This has the disadvantage of effectively traversing the chain at stream construction time already. Also, the result of nested `Stream.concat` can be quite inefficient (the javadoc even warns about this). Though, the chain of causes should not be very long usually…

Answer (score 17):

The problem is the missing stop condition in `Stream.iterate`. In Java 9, you could use

```
Stream.iterate(exception, Objects::nonNull, Throwable::getCause)
```

which is equivalent to Java 9’s

```
Stream.iterate(exception, Throwable::getCause)
      .takeWhile(Objects::nonNull)
```

See [`Stream.iterate`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate-T-java.util.function.Predicate-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-) or [`Stream.takeWhile`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#takeWhile-java.util.function.Predicate-).

Since this feature does not exist in Java 8, a back-port would be required:

```
public static <T> Stream<T>
                  iterate​(T seed, Predicate<? super T> hasNext, UnaryOperator<T> next)
{
    Objects.requireNonNull(next);
    Objects.requireNonNull(hasNext);
    return StreamSupport.stream(
        new Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<T>(Long.MAX_VALUE, Spliterator.ORDERED) {
            T current = seed;
            int state;
            public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
                Objects.requireNonNull(action);
                T value = current;
                if(state > 0) value = next.apply(value);
                else if(state == 0) state = 1;
                else return false;
                if(!hasNext.test(value)) {
                    state = -1;
                    current = null;
                    return false;
                }
                action.accept(current = value);
                return true;
            }
        },
        false);
}
```

The semantic is the same as with Java 9’s `Stream.iterate`:

```
MyStreamFactory.iterate(exception, Objects::nonNull, Throwable::getCause)
               .forEach(System.out::println); // just an example
```

Comment: I am not sure the first java 9 version will work. The second argument is not a stop condition but a `hasNext` predicate. ref:  http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate-T-java.util.function.Predicate-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-

Comment: @balki: `nonNull` *is* the “has next” predicate. Don’t confuse with `isNull`…

Answer (score 9):

The recursive `Stream::concat()` approach creates the entire stream in advance in one recursive call.  The lazy `takeWhile` approach is not available until Java 9.

The following is a lazy, Java 8 approach:

```
class NullTerminated {
    public static <T> Stream<T>  stream(T start, Function<T, T> advance) {
        Iterable<T> iterable = () -> new Iterator<T>() {
            T next = start;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return next != null;
            }

            @Override
            public T next() {
                T current = next;
                next = advance.apply(current);
                return current;
            }           
        };
        return StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Throwable b = new Throwable();
Throwable a = new Throwable(b);

NullTerminated.stream(a, Throwable::getCause).forEach(System.out::println);
```

---

Update: Replacing `Iterator`/`Iterable.spliterator()` with direct construction of a `Spliterator`:

```
class NullTerminated {
    public static <T> Stream<T>  stream(T start, Function<T, T> advance) {
        Spliterator<T> sp = new AbstractSpliterator<T>(Long.MAX_VALUE, Spliterator.ORDERED | Spliterator.NONNULL) {
            T current = start;
            @Override
            public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
                if (current != null) {
                    action.accept(current);
                    current = advance.apply(current);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
        return StreamSupport.stream(sp, false);
    }
}
```

---

Update 2:

For a one-off, efficient, minimal-code implementation that converts the chain of `Throwable` objects into a `Stream<Throwable>` stream, and immediately using said stream:

```
Stream.Builder<Throwable> builder = Stream.builder();
for(Throwable t = a; t != null; t = t.getCause())
    builder.accept(t);
builder.build().forEach(System.out::println);
```

This has the disadvantage of being non-lazy (traversing the entire chain at stream construction time), but avoids the inefficiencies of recursion and Stream.concat().

Comment: I think for my current problem I'll favour @Eugene recursive approach, since it reduces the amount of code, is better understandable for future developers working with the code and my stacktrace parsing is only used in a very specific scenario, so the performance is not an issue. Nevertheless I like this approach very much and would use it if I had more use cases. (Too lazy to write tests for it right now) Thanks for the trouble.

Comment: Funny, I favour the `Stream.iterator()` back-port by @Holger ... Remember all this generic implementation code gets written once and tucked away in a library, where it can be used and re-used for any type `<T>`.  The recursive approach by @Eugene is hard-wired for only `Throwable` objects, so is not directly reusable, and oddly I find less understandable than the `Iterator`/`Spliterator` based streams.  As for future developers: someone may "learn" from that code, and while it might work for a two or three level `Throwable` chain, it has considerable inefficiencies so is not the best example.

Comment: Well, I'm just trying to figure out if there is a ConstraintViolationException hidden in the Stacktrace, for logging the contained validation messages. In our scenario this only happens if a database table is not in sync with the jpa entity and all other exception handling failed. So it is "good enough" for the use case. Nevertheless I have to strongly agree that bad code is like cancer and tries to spread in a project. I've added a comment for future developers to our code that explains the issues with the current solution and links to this question for further reference.

Comment: @Arigion Update 2: added a one-off, efficient, minimal implementation for this single use-case.

Comment: The `Stream.iterate` is not only added to the code base just once, it can also be removed again when switching to Java 9, as the calls can be redirected to the standard API with no effort then.

Answer (score 5):

I have another option via a `Spliterator`:

```
static Stream<Throwable> process(Throwable t) {

    Spliterator<Throwable> sp = new AbstractSpliterator<Throwable>(100L, Spliterator.ORDERED) {

        Throwable inner = t;

        @Override
        public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super Throwable> action) {
            if (inner != null) {
                action.accept(inner);
                inner = inner.getCause();
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    };

    return StreamSupport.stream(sp, false);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you can create a `Stream` with seed `root` (your head `Throwable` in linkedlist). As `UnaryOperator` take is the next `Throwable`.  Example:

```
Stream.iterate(root, Throwable::getNext)
         .takeWhile(node -> node != null)
         .forEach(node -> System.out.println(node.getCause()));
```

Comment: `takeWhile` *will* be available in jdk-9

Comment: besides `node -> node != null` could be replaced with `Objects::nonNull`

Comment: The Stream.iterate(root, Throwable::getNext) already throws a NPE due to the implementaton of iterate: `public static<T> Stream<T> iterate(final T seed, final UnaryOperator<T> f) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(f); ...` I'm not sure if `takeWhile` will be reached

Comment: @Arigion: you are misunderstanding the outcome. `f` is never `null`, as it is your function. But when you traverse the chain of causes, there will be a `null` cause at one point but since you’re not stopping at `null`, you’ll try to invoke `getCause()` on that `null` reference. It’s not that `null` elements are forbidden in general.

Comment: Note that `Stream.iterate(root, Throwable::getCause) .takeWhile(node -> node != null)` is identical to `Stream.iterate(root, node -> node != null, Throwable::getCause)` or `Stream.iterate(root, Objects::nonNull, Throwable::getCause)`, all of them requiring Java 9…

Answer (score 2):

What exactly is wrong with this?

```
while (exception) {
    System.out.println(exception); //or whatever you want to do
    exception = exception.getCause();
}
```

There is no point in being "more functional." Functional style is just a tool, and it's clearly inappropriate here.