# list of ancestors as stream

Tags: java, java-8

How can I turn this while loop into a stream in Java 8?

```
    Location toTest = originalLocation;
    while(true){
        toTest = toTest.getParentLocation();
        if (toTest==null) {
            break;
        }
        parents.add(toTest);
    }
```

Assume that Location is along the lines of :

```
@Data
public class Location{
    private String name;
    private Location parentLocation;
}
```

It seems like it should be :

```
Stream.iterate(location, l -> l.getParentLocation()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but I that gives me a NullPointerException. Which I assume is when `getParentLocation()` returns null...

Can anyone help ?

Comment: What is `location`, and what is `parents`?

Comment: Won't that code loop forever? I mean, `location` is never updated, and I assume it isn't stateful, so `getParentLocation()` always returns the same value. I think you need a `location = l;` at the end of the loop.

Comment: yes.. doh. Let me update that.

Comment: What about `while ((location = location.getParentLocation()) != null) parents.add(location);` ?

Comment: sure, yeah. How do I turn that into a stream in java 8?

Answer (score 4):

JDK9 solution:

```
Stream.iterate(location, Objects::nonNull, Location::getParentLocation)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `generate` will 'repeat'  the parent of `location` forever since `location::getParentLocation` will always return the same instance - it will not change location to its parent after each iteration

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger see the initial post by the OP, that was the cause. I've edited it since.

Comment: still the first one will loop forever... and it is hard to understand since the OP edited the initial post

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is `takeWhile` from java-9:

```
...takeWhile( x -> x != null).collect...
```

Comment: @Aomine IIRC there was a back port from Holger for java-8, but hard to search on the phone

Comment: @Eugene Perhaps, you mean [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46078885/2711488)…

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`iterate​(T seed, Predicate<? super T> hasNext, UnaryOperator<T> next)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate-T-java.util.function.Predicate-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-) overload that was added in Java 9:

```
Stream.iterate(location, l -> l != null, l -> l.getParentLocation())
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Same using method references:

```
Stream.iterate(location, Objects::nonNull, Location::getParentLocation)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```